# Проблема с Redis не работает timeout

Tags: java, redis

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost", 6379, 8);
    jedis.connect();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.println(jedis.isConnected());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println(jedis.isConnected());
```

Вывод в консоль

```
true
true
```

по в конструкторе redis время timeout указывается в секундах так что по задумке не активное подключение по истечению 8 секунд должно закрыться но не закрывается что я делаю не так?

Comment: может Jedis, а не Redis. Не знаю что это за класс такой и что он делает. И п.с если это сокеты, то там нету отслеживание клиента, тоесть они могут отрубится а вы будете думать что они подключены. При запись в поток вывода сокета, вылазит исключение говорящяя что компьютер вас отверг, соединения больше не существует. А isConnect вернет вам true там переменная boolean, он не делает нейких проверок.

Comment: Даже в документацию вас не послать, там в проекте "самодокументирующийся код". В общем, это не тайм-аут неактивности, а тайм-аут блокирующих операций на tcp-сокете (подключение, чтение), в миллисекундах. Т.е. если бы за 8 мс не удалось подключиться, `connect()` выдал бы исключение. Вам вроде-бы нужен `jedis.configSet("timeout", "8");`

Comment: Да вы правы второй вариант мне бы подошел но есть одно но `jedis.configSet("timeout", "8");`
удаляет не активные соединения кожные 8 секунд но мне нужно удалить не все неактивные а только те где установлен таймаут.
другими словами есть ли возможность установить таймаут на подключение которое мы делаем в данный момент и не затрагивать другие подключения?